# How can I append the last row on each dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use for loop to append the last row into a new dataframe. However, it only can append the last data into the new dataframe. May I know how can I fix it?

The code looks like this:

```
list_1 = ['A', 'AAPL', 'U']

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'High', 'Low','Open','Volume','Adj Close','d_return','30d_return'])

for stock in list_1:
    
    dateToday = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    end = '2021-03-27'
    start = ''

    df = web.DataReader(stock,'yahoo',start,end)[-70:]
    
    df['d_return'] = df['Adj Close'].pct_change()
    df['10d_return'] = df['d_return'][-10:].sum()
    df['Ticker'] = stock
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    new_df = df.iloc[[-1]]
    
    new_df.append(blank_df)
    
new_df
```

Comment: Note that I assumed your `blank_df` is not used elsewhere.  Otherwise, you can define a new variable, says, `last_row` to replace the variable `blank_df` here and also change the append statement to append this new variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change the line:

```
new_df = df.iloc[[-1]]
```

to:

```
blank_df = df.iloc[-1]
```

Your code is now resetting `new_df` to a new value in every iteration with the first line above.  Hence, only left with the value set in the last iteration after the loop.

Also, you don't need double square bracket `[[-1]]` for `.iloc`.  Just use .iloc[-1] should bring you the last row of `df`.